# When using multi factor login is a password needed?

Tags: security, authentication, two-factor-authentication

I am designing a multi factor log in.  If the user enters their login name on my website and submits it I will then text them with the temporary code.  once they submit this we will create a session id and complete the login process.  Is having the user enter a password during this process needed? Is it a best practice?

Comment: Why would you not want a password + temporary code?

Comment: If I don't have passwords I don't have to deal with storage, history, complexity and resets.  I am also under the impression that login name is something you know. which is the first factor.

Comment: I don't see lazy as a bad thing.

Comment: Login name does not count as "something you know" because it is "something everybody knows."

Comment: We have a login name, and a user name.  the login name is only used at login time.  So by every one you mean the site administrator?  But then they can change the phone number and reset the password.  I don't  think you can gaurd against that kind of threat?

Comment: In general, the user name is not a secret.  It is usually something that follows a pattern like, first initial, last name.  So you can guess what mine is if you know my name.  And even if you are keeping it secret, and it does not follow any pattern, it is not easy to change.  If you find out my password, then I can change it, but if you find my login name, then what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the password is needed. As described the user never has to enter their password. This is really just single-factor auth. MFA is usually something you know (password) plus something you have (phone, fingerprint, hand geometry, etc). In your design someone could steal the user's phone and then they could get through the login, assuming they know their target's username.

There's also an annoying side-effect where if I know someone's login, I can spam them with text messages from you.

The best practice is to make the user sign in with username + password, once they're past that you ask them if they want to send the text message.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not require a password, then you are relying on the temporary code as the only factor.

This means that someone could steal my phone (or just [steal the phone number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_number_portability)) and it would give them access to this account without even having my password!

No, this is not a good practice.